# How to set JAVA_HOME in Mac permanently?

Tags: java, macos, java-home

I am trying to set `JAVA_HOME` by entering `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home` at terminal.
It sets the `JAVA_HOME` for current session.

How can I set it permanently?

Comment: Here we are in 2019 ( 6 years after original question ) - and this still only has a convoluted solution.  Try supporting macs in the field with this problem.  Is there no utility that will add   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home   to the current user bash profile - or a machine level equivalent ?

Answer (score 138):

You can use `/usr/libexec/java_home -v <version you want>` to get the path you need for `JAVA_HOME`. For instance, to get the path to the 1.7 JDK you can run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` and it will return the path to the JDK. In your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` just add

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v <version>`
```

and you should be good. Alternatively, try and convince the maintainers of java tools you use to make use of this method to get the version they need.

To open '.bash_profile' type the following in terminal :

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and add the following line to the file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v <version>`
```

Press CTRL+X to exit the bash. Press 'Y' to save changes.

To check whether the path has been added, type following in terminal:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: It's not the answer because it does not permanently set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable I suppose, which is what the OP asked for.  This is only `temporary for the current session.`  A reboot will change it back to the permanently set variable.

Comment: Re Android Addict comment: There are no 'permanent' environment variables for shells, that's why you have a .bash_profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, etc. This answer will solve the question and should be chosen.

Comment: I had problems with this approach when having multiple versions of Java installed especially when one of these installed with `brew`

Comment: In my case, this worked for that instance only. Though replacing `bash_profile` with `zshrc` worked for me

Comment: Thank you, please change format answer to the following format. Of course it our responsibility to change version. But anyway I have merged your answer with @Arv answer below. THen It worked. JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home'

Comment: In my case, the first command worked even without "-v <version>". Why is "-v <version>" beneficial? Can you have a separate JAVA_HOME for each version?

Comment: @paradocslover renaming bash_profile to zshrc (I have created bash_profile in the first place) saved my life. Thanks!

Comment: getting all versions use capital V, like: "/usr/libexec/java_home -V"

Answer (score 66):

I was facing the same issue in MAC Catalina, If I edit .bash_profile i found export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
But When I run terminal echo $JAVA_HOME it was returning empty, Later I found that the file .zshrc was missing I created this file with

```
touch .zshrc
```

Then edit it by `nano .zshrc` and wrote

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Which solves my issue permanently

Comment: Worked for MAC Catalina solve..! Thanks for sharing the tip!

Comment: Wowww...That's Awesome. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I am using jenv and figured out that adding JAVA_HOME after jenv configuration in zshrc file sets the JAVA_HOME variable else I was getting an empty value.

`export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_252)`

Comment: This is genius!

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer, it worked for me as well.

Comment: I think only Oh_my_zsh users need to modify zshrc file.

Comment: You people are mixing zsh and bash. They are different terminal shells. Use .bashrc for bash config and .zshrc for zsh config. Don't mix them.

Comment: Perfect answer. working on Monterey.

Answer (score 30):

Installing Java on `macOS 11 Big Sur`:

- the easiest way is to select OpenJDK 11 (LTS), the HotSpot JVM, and macOS x64 is to get the latest release here: [adoptopenjdk.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot)
- Select macOS and x64 and download the `JDK` (about 190 MB), which will put the `OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_11.0.9_11.pkg` file into your `~/Downloads folder`
- Clicking on pkg file, will install into this location: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk`
  [image]
- Almost done. After opening a terminal, the successful installation of the JDK can be confirmed like so: `java --version`

  - output:

```bash
openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9.1+1, mixed mode)
```

- `JAVA_HOME` is an important environment variable and it’s important to get it right. Here is a trick that allows me to keep the environment variable current, even after a Java Update was installed. In `~/.zshrc`, I set the variable like so:
  `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`
- In previous macOS versions, this was done in `~/.bash_profile`. Anyway, open a new terminal and verify: `echo $JAVA_HOME`

  - output: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home`

---

TEST: Compile and Run your Java Program

- Open a text editor, copy the code from below and save the file as `HelloStackoverflow.java`.

```java
public class HelloStackoverflow {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello Stackoverflow !");
  }//End of main
}//End of HelloStackoverflow Class
```

- From a terminal set the working directory to the directory containing `HelloStackoverflow.java`, then type the command:

```bash
javac HelloStackoverflow.java
```

- If you're lucky, nothing will happen
- Actually, a lot happened. `javac` is the name of the Java compiler. It translates Java into `Java Bytecode`, an assembly language for the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). The Java Bytecode is stored in a file called `HelloStackoverflow.class`.
- Running: type the command:

```bash
java HelloStackoverflow

# output:
# Hello Stackoverflow !
```

[image]

Comment: since yesterday i am trying to write it to the .bash_profile file and wondering why it is not working. **.zshrc** file !!! You saved my day. Thank you

Comment: @Kerem It depends what is your default shell Set. You can know this by doing `echo $SHELL` If it is `/bin/bash` then you need to change in .bash_profile, if it is `/bin/zsh` then you should set it in .zshrc file.

Comment: this worked on Monterey!

Comment: open new terminal and hit this cmd for open bash file 
xxxxx@XXX-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd ~/
xxxx@XXX-MacBook-Pro ~ % touch ~/
xxxx@XXX-MacBook-Pro ~ % open -e .bash_profile

Answer (score 21):

To set your Java path on mac:

1. Open terminal on mac, change path to the root cd ~
2. vi .bash_profile (This opens the bash_profile file)
3. Click **I** to insert text and use the following text to set JAVA_HOME and PATH

   - export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home'
   - export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

     4. Type :wq to save and exit the file.
     5. Type source .bash_profile to execute the .bash_profile file.
     6. You can type echo $JAVA_HOME or echo $PATH

Comment: I tried this, it changes for the shell session, but has no effect on a new shell session.

Comment: Mac OS automatically executes .bash_profile on every terminal session.Are you still facing the issue ? Did you try restarting ?

Comment: ~/.bash_profile is not a default file; most won't have it, so you can't just start editing it. And you can't just create it because it has syntax; it needs to be a full script file.

Answer (score 14):

Try this link 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/

This explains correctly, I did the following to make it work

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `vim .bash_profile`
3. Type your java instalation dir in my case `export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`
4. Click `ESC` then type `:wq` (save and quit in vim)
5. Then type `source .bash_profile`
6. `echo $JAVA_HOME` if you see the path you are all set.

Hope it helps.

Comment: THIS is the answer, not all the other stuff above.  (Though note that Dilip left off the trailing " at the end of line 3.)

Answer (score 13):

Besides the settings for bash/ zsh terminal which are well covered by the other answers, if you want a permanent system environment variable for terminal + GUI applications (works for macOS Sierra; should work for El Capitan too):

```
launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

(this will set JAVA_HOME to the latest 1.8 JDK, chances are you have gone through serveral updates e.g. javac 1.8.0_101, javac 1.8.0_131)

Of course, change 1.8 to 1.7 or 1.6 (really?) to suit your need and your system

Comment: This is the correct answer for GUI Applications (not the OP's question, though...). Work like charm on macOS Sierra.

Comment: This command dont work on terminal.Anyone? tried the bash_profile and nothing.

Answer (score 9):

run this command on your terminal(here -v11 is for version 11(java11))-:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v11
```

you will get the path on your terminal something like this -:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home
```

now you need to open your bash profile in any editor for eg VS Code

if you want to edit your bash_profile in vs code then run this command -:

```
code ~/.bash_profile
```

else run this command and then press i to insert the path. -:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

you will get your .bash_profile now you need to add the path
so add this in .bash_profile (path which you get from 1st command)-:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home
```

if you were using code editor then now go to terminal and run this command to save the changes -:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

else press esc then :wq to exit from bash_profile then go to terminal and run the command given above.
process completed.
now you can check using this command -:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

you will get`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 9):

To set JAVA_HOME permanently in Mac, I tried following steps.

1. Download and install Java JDK to your Mac. When you install a Java JDK version which will be installed in the following location by default in MAC.

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

2. Open the **.bash_profile** file (Here My Mac version is MacOS High Sierra. You may need to open **.zshrc** file in some different MacOS versions).

`atom ~/.bash_profile`

3. Add following to your bash_profile file.

Change the JDK version accordingly

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home'
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

4. Open the Terminal and execute following.

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Open a new terminal and check 'echo $JAVA_HOME'

Thanks.

Comment: You only need the second line saying export JAVA_HOME since it will overwrite the value of JAVA_HOME set on the line before it.

Comment: Oh, and on my M1 Mac, I put the export line (thagt I needed) in the file ~/.zshenv e.g.:
`export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Answer (score 7):

This link may helps you: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1067/_index.html

Also, you can put the environment variable in one of these files:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
```

Answer (score 7):

the answers here are in general correct, but for me I didn't know that I need to do something like `source ~/.bash_profile` to be able to really make it work.

so the full answer is:

```
nano ~/.zshenv // or
nano ~/.zshrc // or
nano ~/.bash_profile
//add this line to zshrc and bash_profile if you want to be 100% sure
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
//save
source ~/.bash_profile //the KEY that generally isn't in the answers
source ~/.zshrc //I didn't do this one, but maybe you need it
```

Answer (score 4):

1) The first step is to if you have Java installed and running your system.

```
which java
```

Usually, it should be /usr/bin/java.

2) **JAVA_HOME** is essentially the full path of the directory that contains a sub-directory named **bin** which in turn contains the **java**.

```
cd /Library/Java/
```

- You should have **bin** folder inside **/Java** folder and in turn it must contain the **[java]** executable package.

[Folder structure for Mac OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDSy3.png)

3.1) If you want to set the path only for the current session then execute this command in your terminal `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java`

3.2) If you want it to persist, you will have to add the command to your `~/.bash_profile` file

- Open up Terminal `vi ~/.bash_profile`
- Add these lines to terminal `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home` and save it
- Execute below command `source ~/.bash_profile`

4) Verify you have correctly added JAVA_HOME path. Below command should give you the proper Java version.

That's it and your ready to use!!

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Dilips's answer, if you are working with JDK 9, use the following (my JDK version is 9.0.4) in Step # 3:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried 5 different things, but your solution actually helped me. Using macOS 10.14.5 (18F132) and setting JDK version.

Answer (score 3):

[sql-surfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2080879/sql-surfer) and
[MikroDel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502950/mikrodel),

actually, the answer is not that complicated! You just need to add:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

to your shell profile/configuration file. The only question is - which shell are you using? If you're using for example FISH, then adding that line to `.profile` or `.bash_profile` will not work at all. Adding it to `config.fish` file though will do the trick. Permanently.

Answer (score 3):

First, figure out where your java home is by running the command `/usr/libexec/java_home -v <version>` replacing  with whatever version of OpenJDK your running.

Next use `vim ~/.bash_profile` to edit your bash profile. Add `export JAVA_HOME="<java path>"` replacing  with the path to your java home found in the last step.

Finally, run the command `source ~/.bash_profile`

This should permanently set your JAVA_HOME environment variable.

To make sure it worked run `echo $JAVA_HOME` and make sure it returns the path you set

Answer (score 2):

to set JAVA_HOME permenantly in mac make sure you have JDK installed in your system,
if jdk is not installed you can download it from here
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

After installing jdk follow these steps :-

1) Open Terminal

2) Type "vim .bash_profile"

3) press "i" to edit or enter the path

4) Type your java instalation dir :- export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

5) Click ESC then type ":wq" (save and quit in vim)

6) Then type "source .bash_profile"

7) type "echo $JAVA_HOME" if you see the path you are all set.

THANK YOU

Comment: (This requires vim too though, doesn't it? Not that bad of a problem, but the user has to install it.)

Comment: vim is pre installed in mac

Comment: one either use vi or even textmate. which sh'd not be an issue

Answer (score 2):

Declare two export inside your .bashrc or .zshrc:

```
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8) 
export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)
```

Add alias for quick change:

```
alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME'
```

set default to Java 11

```
java11
```

export PATH

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

you could change java11 by java8 inside your .bashrc/zshrc file to change permanently your java version

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest versions of macOS, then you cannot use ~/.bash_profile to export your environment variable since the bash shell is deprecated in the latest version of macOS.

- Run `/usr/libexec/java_home` in your terminal and you will get things like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home`
- Add `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home` to .zshrc

Answer (score 2):

If you are using fish shell. Then all the variables can be set in .config/fish/config.fish

```
vim .config/fish/config.fish
```

Add the following lines

```
set -g JAVA_HOME "your_path_to_jdk"
```

save and exit out of vim.

This should be setting your JAVA_HOME. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find out the jenv will set the $JAVA_HOME a short version like "/Users/*****/.jenv/versions/1.8".

Have to uninstall jenv to make the $JAVA_HOME setting works like "JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home"

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers were suggesting to source .bash_profile were outdated for me, I'm using **macOS Ventura 13.4.1** which uses Zsh shell. Knowing which shell you are using helps you determine which configuration file to modify.

**Step 1:**

```
 echo $SHELL
```

**Step 2:**

if you see /bin/zsh then you need to update JAVA_HOME in ~/.zshrc, oterwise if you're seeing /bin/bash you need to update JAVA_HOME in ~/.bash_profile. Here ~/ is the home path. you can find .zshrc and .bash_profile in your home directory. you can go to you home directory by pressing return after `cd`

**Step 3**

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

run this command to see the jdks installed on your mac.

**Step 4**

I was using the Zsh shell, so I had to add this export in my .zshrc file. if you don't have this file in you `~/` home direcroy you need to create it.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`
```

replace the version after -v to the version you want to permanently set and aready have installed.

**Step 5**

if you're using Zsh shell

```
source .zshrc
```

else

```
source .bash_profile
```

make sure you're running this command in your home directory if you're not in your home directory run `source ~/.zshrc` as ~/ is shorthand for home directory.

Answer (score 0):

add following

```
setenv JAVA_HOME /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
```

in your  ~/.login file:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the java version permanently,
i.e., If you have 2 or more Java versions in your local

Then, follow these steps:

**1.** Check the available java versions using
"/usr/libexec/java_home -V" command

[image]

**2.** Set the path inside the .bash_profile

- Open your terminal
- vi .bash_profile
- export
  JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home

Here, "*/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home*"
is the java11 version path from step 1

Answer (score 0):

In .bash_profile you add this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.8/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In .zshrc you add this

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Command + Q in iTerm2, open again and:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```