# Android Studio Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new in Android Studio. After setup, 
When I am trying to import an application I am getting that error So that gradle not able to build.

**Error:Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper**

I checked that my classpath setting for Java is fine.  I am running Windows OS.  Does anyone know the source of the error?

Comment: Did you check your "JAVA_HOME" variable?

Comment: Yes Everything fine..

Comment: See [“Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted” error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641042/11667949)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I faced this issue because of lower version of Jdk.
Previously I installed **Jdk 1.7** and **Android Studio 1.5.1**, I got this issue.
If you install **Android Studio 1.5.1** or above JDK 1.8 required

So **Installing JDK 1.8 solved this issue.**

Comment: this is not enough

Answer (score 351):

Please make changes as per below to resolve this error.

> **Install Java SDK version:** 14 or above.

JDK Download link: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html

> In `gradle-wrapper.properties` please use grade version **6.3** or above.

For e.g:`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip`

Comment: Updating the Gradle from 6.0.1-all to 6.3-all solved the problem on Mac OS Catalina, tks. React-native build by the way.

Comment: I am using Java 14. with Gradle 6.4 but the problem still exists for me.

Comment: BEST ANSWER, why is this not included in the ReactNative init.

Comment: this worked with me "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip"

Comment: thanks, this really helped me! why is this happening? could I use a lower gradle version(perhaps also a lower java version) and still get it to work?

Comment: Updating the Gradle from 5.6.2-all to 6.5-all solved the problem on Windows, For Flutter

Comment: you saved my day, just for me required a further step which is rebuild gradle in android studio in mac OS.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"

Answer (score 186):

1. This is because of the gradle version.
2. Go to: `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.
3. Change a version of the course by this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

The console outputs:

```
Welcome to Gradle 6.3!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Java 14 support
 - Improved error messages for unexpected failures

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me given that I am in a react native project and JAVA 14 / Open JDK!

Comment: I'm on `java version "15" 2020-09-15` and this worked for me on MacOS Catalina.

Comment: Thanks this helped. Not sure why this was not yet selected as the accepted answer.

Comment: If you go to the URL `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/` this will list the versions, then edit your gladle-wrapper.properties file with the relevant link and click `retry`

Comment: this was the ideal solution for me, even my gradle on 6.2 version didn't work, just switching to 6.3 that started working

Comment: This is the correct solution as of 1 des 20

Comment: Apparently, this is not a global solution. I updated gradle with the provided URL. I received a different errors, `Could not open settings remapped class cache for...`, `Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file`, and `BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60`

Got the same error when using `6.4.1`

Answer (score 39):

First watch this and try reinstall - https://youtu.be/trHinrIm6DM

After if you get "Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper"

1.install Java SDK 14 and update env path.

2."[Your RN or Flutter Project Folder]\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties" this file edit as ...(upgrade gradle version)

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

3.run gradlew in cmd path "[Your RN or Flutter Project Folder]\android\"

4.it takes time.after if shows "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" you can "flutter run" in ur project folder

Yeah It's work

Comment: Thanks a lot, i couldnt find a solution anywhere else.

Comment: I was beginner in react native and was scratching my head from so long to run Android device !! .Y ou are amazing Man  !!! you saved my time and thanks  that you have a great attitude to help others like this clean information !!

Comment: command should be ./gradlew not gradlew . Everything else works fine

Comment: how about the old projects? with distribution 5.~.zip and jdk 14

Answer (score 27):

What was helpful for me (MacBook):

- first go to **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart**
- then check the value of **JAVA_HOME** enviroment variable, by calling `echo $JAVA_HOME` (it should be equal to **"/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"**)
- if it is not, change its value by calling `export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"`

Comment: This is actually worked with me without the need to update wrapper version, the case that I did a fresh install on my macOS and installed a lot of things and this could have changed the JAVA_HOME and cause this issue, thanks a lot

Comment: This worked for me. But it sort of gets reset on every bootup. How can I make this change permanent?

Comment: This saved my life

Comment: Hey @sudonitin, check there to see how to save enviroment variables permanently: 
https://medium.com/@youngstone89/setting-up-environment-variables-in-mac-os-28e5941c771c

Comment: This is huge because you DO NOT have to go through the trouble of installing Java if you have Android Studio. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957460 for shell config to set some things automatically.

Comment: This is not working for me because the Path Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation., However following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19663996/4696051  allowed me to find the correct Java Home Path in MacOs Catalina /usr/libexec/java_home

Comment: Thank you, you save my live

Answer (score 10):

I'm using Pop OS 20.04 and I have Java versions 8, 11 and 14 installed on my notebook.

This error was happening to me when version 14 was standard.

When I switched to using version 11 as the default, the error no longer occurred.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Switching to Java 8 worked for me (I didn't have 11 installed). Thanks!

Comment: switched 11 version and worked for  me (pop-os)

Answer (score 8):

In gradle-wrapper.properties file, updating the Gradle to 6.3 solved the problem on Mac OS Catalina

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip

Comment: where can I get gradle-wrapper.properties file please ?

Comment: You can get it at path "YOUR_PROJECT/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties"

Comment: For react native, it's slightly different: `YOUR_PROJECT/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Answer (score 7):

In my case the problem was that my version of Gradle was incompatible with JDK 14, but despite in project structure dialog was selected JDK 8.

It was necessarily to set JDK home for Gradle separately in `gradle.propperties`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to `\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`.
2. Update the installing [distribution version (all.zip) of Gradle](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) in `distributionUrl`. As an example for Gradle version 6.8:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-all.zip

Answer (score 5):

I face this issue when I was Building my Flutter Application.
This error is due to the gradle version that you are using in your Android Project.
Follow the below steps:

- Install jdk version 14.0.2 from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html .
- If using Windows open C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin , Copy the Path and now update the path ( Reffer to this article for updating the path : https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/ .
- Open the Project that you are working on
  [Your Project]\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
  and now Replace the distributionUrl with the below line:

> distributionUrl = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip

Now Save the File (Ctrl + S), Go to the console and run the command

> flutter run

It will take some time, but the issue that you were facing will be solved.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and great contribution!

Comment: Super! Works like a charm in Flutter!!

Answer (score 5):

So, you are in 2022, and changing the distribution URL does not work?

Yeah, React Native is such a pain. Make sure you have followed the [React Native official guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), then check the Java version with:

```
java -version
```

Check [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) of Gradle versions. Change distribution URL to the version accordingly, from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-X.X-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-Y.Y-all.zip
```

where `Y.Y` is the suitable version for your Java version.

And now, check that `$JAVA_HOME` is set:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

*Damn, is empty!*

Yes, this environment variable is required, and on Internet you will see examples of exporting this path, for example for MacOS:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"
```

**Be careful**, this is not always the correct path. Check it navigating using `cd` command. For me the path was:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"
```

*Spot the difference*. This could be anywhere, so check it carefully as this is the last step that will allow you to run your project with `yarn example android`

Tested on: macOS Bug Sur, version 11.4. Intel Core i5. Good luck with M1.

PS: I hate React Native required configurations.

Comment: There you go. Thanks for this lifesaver :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my case was in the discrepancy between the Gradle version installed globally and the one required by React Native. To fix it, I had to update the folder `android/gradle/wrapper` from [the current 6.5 RN version from GH](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/gradle/wrapper).

Comment: Also see [“Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted” error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641042/11667949https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641042/11667949)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it just by editing the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

You must go to the project folder, then `/android/grandle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.
In DistributionUrl, change to `https \: //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jdk 16 downgrade to 14 and gradle-wrapper.properties use 6.3 don't forget to upgrade build gradle in build.gradle to 4+

Answer (score 2):

So I also got the same error on my system when I Cloned a project from github.
The project that i created on my system worked without any errors.
So if you are also in similar situation this could help
1-Go to this path

```
project-name/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

2-Replace everything inside with this

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade to the latest version of the gradle in the gradle-wrapper.properties file
i.e.    `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip`
please do not forget to change the gradle version in the build.gradle file as well

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '6.6.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when I open a new project with VS Code & Flutter. I solved the problem by editing the gradle.build and gradle-wrapper.properties files.

**Edit `android>build.gradle` like this:**

> dependencies {
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
> classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.3.3' //add this line
> classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin: kotlin-gradle-plugin: $ kotlin_version" }

**Edit `gradle-wrapper.properties`**

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip

Comment: This is the same answer that @josileudo provided.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and and it looks like this problem is due to the gradle version in the project directory

- This is the version of my jdk:

```
openjdk version "15-ea" 2020-09-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15-ea+32-Ubuntu-220.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15-ea+32-Ubuntu-220.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

- Please check gradle whether it is installed. This is the version of my gradle:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-01-08 16:38:46 UTC
Revision:     b7e82460c5373e194fb478a998c4fcfe7da53a7e

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          15-ea (Private Build 15-ea+32-Ubuntu-220.04)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-65-generic amd64
```

- Then open the gradle-wrapper.properties file in your project folder, in the folder: `project name/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
- Change the gradle version. Here I changed the gradle version to 6.5

The video version can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcclcscUpV0

Answer (score 1):

Resolve It:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip
```

and I changed it into:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when building the Flutter project, I edited this file gradle-wrapper.properties
location: android -> grade\wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties

from this to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

to this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

but was not solved, I did `flutter doctor` and found some error in the android toolchain. I open android studio and installed "Android SDK Command-line tools" in SDK manager.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69604498/13577765

and was solved.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for M1 Mac User

Find your local Java version by typing `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`. If didn't exist, install the latest ARM Java version here
Set Java_Home path (in my case jdk-17.0.1.jdk) by typing

`/usr/libexec/java_home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`

Type all of these in terminal

> `cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre ln -s ../jre jdk ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk`

Finally run flutter doctor -v to see all the details changes

Answer (score 0):

gradle-wrapper.properties please use grade version 6.3 or above

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip

../android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to upgrade the gradle version to 6.3 from the android project structure (java 14.0.1 is already installed on my pc).

Answer (score 0):

(Solution)
I tried my first flutter app in android studio , i was getting same error " Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper"

open build.gradle and update dependencies

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

or just hover over com.android.tools.build:grandle:(your-version)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried "react-native run-android" I was receiving errors "Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper" + "Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up"....

Solved it by updating the gradle in Android Studio. When I opened my project in Android Studio it showed a message asking to update Gradle, and I just clicked.

Comment: I did the same. In my case, it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to change distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties, you also need to change gradle version in your project structure.

1. Go to gradle-wrapper.properties and change:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-all.zip

2. Go to Android studio -> file -> project structure

Change gradle verison to 6.8 or whatever verison you selected that is compatible with your jdk.