# How to set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in mac?

Tags: android, macos, cordova, android-emulator

I am trying to use Cordova for mobile app development. For now I am focusing on Android. I am trying to run `cordova emulate android`. It runs and after a long list of packages it says ‘build successful’ but in the end it also says:

> PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

I use Homebrew. Here is output of the command:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.345 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /users/mayurtolani/myMobileApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5_API_24
Waiting for emulator to start...
PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

Comment: Did you install the Android SDK via homebrew? If so, try the steps outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19986294/483658).

Comment: just install android studio for mac, it will install all you need automatically and you will have no problems with avd system path.

Comment: As far as using the Genymotion emulator and having the Google Apps installed on it, check out [this guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support) on Codepath.

Comment: try the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39711435/2808137

Answer (score 103):

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Then add the following environment variables:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
```

Android path might be different, if so change it accordingly. At last, to refresh the terminal to apply changes:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: That happened to work for me, so thanks. But it is one of 3 popular locations according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: this solution perfectly work for me . just need to restart your mac after editing the file

Comment: @UmarAbbas Mac is not a Windows, you don't need to restart it every 5 minutes... As in answer stated at the end, just use `source` command

Comment: @biesior correct, if you restart your mac every time you make some config, you're gonna have a hard time.

Comment: @RenatoDamas the best way is when soft developer... uses his brain ;) a lot of things can be loaded without forcing end-users to reboot. Otherwise, the very first thing I always try if there's no other option is just logging-off an on, without rebooting. In most cases works. Of course in case of simple `source your-file` we don't have this problem.

Comment: @biesior indeed, except if you're on a Windows. In that case you're just better off rebooting :)

Comment: @RenatoDamas, would you mind addressing a similar issue I'm having.  I'm not sure what to do at this point.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65375107/how-would-i-update-my-android-sdk-root-java-home-path-environment-variables

Comment: It seems the 3rd one is not valid anymore at the moment of this writing

Answer (score 17):

Since you used Homebrew, you can add this to your path:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

Hope I helped! :D

Answer (score 17):

I was facing similar problem. I already downloaded Android SDK as well as Android studio so there were two paths of Android Home. To run emulator and remove error of Android sdk root not set use below steps.

1. Set the path of android sdk which is downloaded by Android Studio.
2. If you already have SDK downloaded in sdk folder copy them in Android studio generated folder. **/Library/Android/sdk**
3. Set the bash profile and add paths as shown below.

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{your pc name}/Library/Android/sdk
   export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
   ```

Answer (score 9):

### Update 2021

If you are a hybrid cordova/ionic/react app developer. Here's what worked for me. All the other answers failed. So i'm sharing my answer

**1. Find the correct JAVA_HOME path on your machine**

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

**2. Copy that path associated with "Java SE 8" which usually looks like** `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home`

**3. create a `~/.bash_profile` or  `~/.zshrc` file**. Here I'm using touch because I dislike nano or vim in the terminal. touch is a regular text editor which I'm more comfortable editing with. Use whatever you like.

```
   touch ~/.bash_profile;
    
   touch ~/.zshrc;
```

**4. edit and copy/paste this in your `~/.bash_profile` or  `~/.zshrc` file**

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools  
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/user198559/Library/Android/sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**5. Save your file with **file->save** like you would save any regular file, *after that* write this in your terminal**

```
source ~/.bash_profile;

source ~/.zshrc;
```

**6. check if path variables are set correctly by opening new terminal**

```
echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home

echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

/Users/user198559/Library/Android/sdk

echo $ANDROID_HOME (deprecated)

(should return empty)
```

Comment: Hi, I followed the same steps as you mentioned but if I quit my terminal and reopen and check "echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" it returns empty. but after running "source ~/.bash_profile" it showing the path.

is there any way to fix permanently this?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Grogu's answer, try this paths. It worked for my **M1 mac**. Make sure you have Android Studio installed.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0)

#SDK exporting
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk

#Tools exporting
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Comment: after some time I had to update java on my mac, in order to do that I had to replace the first line with the following: `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.17)`. Prior to do that, make sure you installed java 11. *Be careful with versioning*.

Answer (score 2):

`ANDROID_HOME` is necessary also, it should be same as `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.
FYI:you need restart `Android Studio` after you changed your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same problem with ionic framework. First, I checked in AVD manager in Android Studio(tools->Android) that all devices run and it was one device without api version. So I changed and test the device. Then i run ionic emulate again and works fine. Also, you could use --target=Device_Name to run a specific device.

Answer (score 0):

In my OSX terminal, i have avoided this error by manually adding the name of the Virtual device that i can read under "AVD name" from AVD manager.

```
ionic emulate android --target="AVD name"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my New Macbook air M1 I am using Android Bumblebee version got the same issue so below is the step which helped me

Go to File -> Project structure -> On the left side menu SDK Location
-> at the bottom of SDK Location section click on Gradle Settings which would be in blue colour -> A Gradle dialog will pop up then click on the Gradle JDK dropdown and select "Android Studio java home" and click on okay.

Then click on Build menu on top -> Clean Project
Then click on Build menu on top -> Rebuild Project

Run the app again error might have gone
Hope this would have helped