# How would I update my ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables on a MAC to build Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic Cordova cross platform app.  When i run ionic cordova build android I get the following error.

```js
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: Processed 65 source files in 1452ms
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/anonymous/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 15.0.1
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

Here is my java version:

java version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)

Everything was working until I downloaded the latest Java SDK, now I can't build Android.

I read in another Stack post that this is bad:
java version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)

I'm not really sure how to resolve this and why the Java SDK doesn't appear when I check Java -version.

I set this in my .bash_profile
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/anonymous/Library/Android/sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android fully supports java 7 and a subset of java 8 and 9 features. So, yes, the JDK 15 you downloaded is not compatible with the Android development platform.

[AdoptOpenJDK 1.8](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8) is the preferred JDK for Android development (don't quote me on this, there may be disagreements)

Then, from the build log you can see `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)`. That's fine, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` can be undefined.

After you've downloaded the correct JDK, the only two environment you need to set are:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
```