# Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Tags: java, android

I tried to build my project and run the app using Android studio and it works fine but when I tried the same using terminal command, it gave me below error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

I saw some other answers but all suggest to upgrade the JDK which I already did but no luck

I am using jdk : java 14 2020-03-17

Gradle version : 5.6.4

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer;

[#8613355](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62027565/8613355)

upgrading your Gradle version in the

```
 gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

will solve your problem.