# Gradle error: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I need to see my dependencies in Gradle to fix a problem with multiple SLF4J bindings.
However, when I run 'gradle dependencies' I get the error:

*Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper*

In a similar question in stack-overflow [Android Studio Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000729/android-studio-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhel)
it was recommended to

1. install java jdk-14
2. upgrade to gradle version 6.3

I changed the jdk to 14 in IntelliJ in 2 places:

1. File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK
2. Preferences -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM

I attempted to update gradle from the command line with:
'gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.3'
and got the same error:

*Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper*

I then changed the field 'distributionUrl' in the file 'gradle-wrapper.properties' to 'gradle-6.3', as instructed here https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10248.

I tried various combinations of jdk and gradle versions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What does `gradlew -version` show on the command line?

Comment: `gradlew -version` gives `-bash: gradlew: command not found`. There are however gradlew and gradlew.bat files in the current directory. `gradle -version` gives `Gradle 6.0.1 ... Kotlin: 1.3.50 Groovy: 2.5.8 Ant: 1.10.7 JVM: 14 OS: Mac OS X 10.15.4 x86_64.

Comment: try `./gradlew -version`. Is this an android app?  Is is an app that's publicly available, so I can try it locally?

Comment: `./gradlew -version` downloaded `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-bin.zip` and then gave `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not determine java version from '14'`.

Comment: the code is on my github page: https://github.com/jspinak/brobotREST

Comment: Yeah, gradle 4 doesn't work with Java 14

Comment: I'll take a look when I get some free time 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So from your repo, if you have gradle-wrapper.properties like this:

```
➜ cat gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

On first compilation, Gradle tells you that:

```
  build file '/Users/tim/Code/Java/brobotREST/build.gradle': 36:
     all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script
```

So if you move the `buildscript` section up to the top of the build.gradle file, it all seems to work

And I get:

```
➜ ./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          14 (Azul Systems, Inc. 14+36)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.4 x86_64
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for helping me out, I really appreciate it :) I made the changes but nothing changed. What's also strange is that I never got the `buildscript` error message that you did. The program always compiled successfully for me, even with `buildscript` at the bottom of the build.gradle file. It gives a couple warnings: `annotationProcessor intersects with a source root`, but compiles. As you instructed, I...

Comment: ... put the `buildscript` section at the top and tried to run `./gradlew -version` again, but with the same results. The build also compiles and gives the same output. I then deleted the whole `buildscript` section (I hadn't set up the local repository yet anyway). Same results :/

Comment: @JoshuaSpinak I sent a PR to your project to add the wrapper properties and jar to the repo...  That's working on my machine...  Check you're running `./gradlew tasks` or `./gradlew -version`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on macOS. It seems, it was a problem with version difference by IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle.
I adjusted the Gradle version in /gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties.
In my case I have set:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip`

and now it works.
See also Gradle: Could not initialize class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62315496/gradle-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhelper)

Comment: It is also recommended to execute ```./gradlew clean``` after changes in ```distributionUrl```.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem on Windows 10 caused by a java version issue.
In **build.gradle** set the java source compatibility flag; For **java 1.8** this is

**sourceCompatibility = '1.8'**

then check the system version is the same

**java -version**