# JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH (Android Studio)

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

I updated my android studio to 4.1.0 just after that my project (in flutter) has been giving this error constantly.

I downgraded my android studio back to 4.0.1 (the previous version I was using), I still am getting the same error.

I saw some articles on the same error in StackOverflow, it suggested to downgrade but it didn't work, the rest of the suggestions are too complicated for me as I am just a beginner.

I even tried changing Project SDK under Project Structure but even that didn't work.
[image]

After installing java jdk (from oracle windowsx64) and changing path name and value as suggested here [Setting JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161248/setting-java-home/11161326#11161326) , I am now getting a whole set of another error, which I basically don't understand a bit.

[image]

Comment: did you set the JAVA_HOME Variable?

Comment: No, to be honest, I don't even know how to do that.

Comment: Linux or windows you are using?

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 to be specific.

Comment: Here you can try this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161248/setting-java-home/11161326#11161326)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can try this [Set JAVA_HOME](http://Here%20you%20can%20try%20this%20enter%20link%20description%20here)
This solution for window 10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62315496/gradle-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhelper

Comment: Here is the help if it is work don't forget to give credits

Answer (score 1):

Kindly go through the process adding JAVA_HOME environment variable, seems JAVA is not in environment variable.

User this link: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html as reference.

once done you can confirm if all is set by running ***javac*** command

Comment: Could you please look into your versions you are running, with Gradle check at android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and update the versions then build again.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is caused when JAVA_HOME path is missing or wrongly valued.

But be sure to check that you have JAVA jdk installed first. (I didn't and that's where everything went wrong).

Then follow this [Setting JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161248/setting-java-home/11161326#11161326) and remember to put proper location with proper version number.

Even after that if you get the second error just follow this [Android Studio Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000729/android-studio-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhel)