# Run a Flutter Project with Android Studio is not possible anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, android-virtual-device

I startet my Flutter project via Android Studio for a while and i had no problem to code and to run this project from e AVD oder a physiical Device (via USB). One week ago, i had a problem because of JAVA_HOME. I could solved this problem but its still not possible to run this problem. Bow i have this message when i try to run my project:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

What can i do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000729/android-studio-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhel  is that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

**1-** project fence

**2-** select Android / gradle / wrapper / gradle-wrapper.properties

**3-** change the `distributionUrl` line
to `https \: //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip`

That solves your problem?

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xrPv.png)

They asked the same thing here

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000729/android-studio-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhel
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i could do this with success. 

It's still not possible to run my project. When I click to "run", i receive this message:

Comment: Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Android Studio\utile_dulci\android\app\build.gradle' line: 41

Comment: * What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Android Studio\utile_dulci\android\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Android Studio\utile_dulci\android\app\build.gradle': 41: unexpected token: utile_dulci @ line 41, column 23.
             applicationId 
utile_dulci                           
^

Comment: 1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 998ms
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: You you know what I could do now?

Comment: It has the complete error message, in the last flutter update the version 6.5 is used and neither the 6.3     gradle   'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'