# running into error on install flutter(java class path)

Tags: java, flutter

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
this is the error message

Answer (score 0):

try `flutter doctor`
if you are getting error in android toolchain

go to the android studio in tools -> SDK manager -> Android SDK Command-line tools
and install it
[image]

[image]

- reopen the terminal, enter `flutter doctor`
- next enter `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
- press y to accept all the licenses

if every thing goes will you should ge some thing like this:
[image]