# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, controlsfx

I'm following the instructions from [controlsfx](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx) to play with ControlsFX sample application. It says

```
simply run
./gradlew run
```

and I got *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError*:

```
 What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
 Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
 Exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.<init>(DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.<init>(DefaultConvention.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ExtensibleDynamicObject.<init>(ExtensibleDynamicObject.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.MixInExtensibleDynamicObject.<init>(MixInExtensibleDynamicObject.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated.getAsDynamicObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsFactory.createSettings(SettingsFactory.java:58)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.initialization.PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.process(PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.process(SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.java:34)
        at org.gradle.initialization.RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.process(RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.process(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:102)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:45)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(DefaultSettingsPreparer.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.doLoadBuild(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:59)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.run(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:42)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareSettings(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:194)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:138)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:130)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 426ms
```

My java version:

```
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-39)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My gradle version:

```
Gradle 7.3

Build time:   2021-11-09 20:40:36 UTC
Revision:     96754b8c44399658178a768ac764d727c2addb37

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.1+12-39)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Nothing mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000729/android-studio-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhel) actually helped.
I downloaded the latest open-jdk, gradle and sources of ControlsFx on clean environment, I haven't modified anything so what could possibly go wrong?