# emmulator is not run in visual studio code Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Tags: android, flutter

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 914ms

gradle version is old?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000729/android-studio-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhel)