# Could not determine java version from '11.0.1' when try to run gradle command

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am able to build my Android project from Android Studio. However, I am getting following error when I try to run a gradlew command. How can I resolve this?

```
admin:(my/branch)$ ./gradlew clean assembleDebug --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
admin:(my/branch)$
```

This is my Java version:

```
admin:(my/branch)$ java -version
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to Gradle 4.7.

The [Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/release-notes.html) says:

> #### Fixed issues
>
> 46 issues have been fixed in Gradle 4.7.
>
> - ...
> - [[#4515](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4515)] - Support Java 11 Version Name
> - ...

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for your answert. You are right. I just upgraded from `gradle-wrpper.propertise` file and I don't see the error. However, this time I see following error:```admin:(my/branch)$ ./gradlew clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().``` Have you seen such an issue?

Comment: I uninstalled Java 11 and installed Java 8 instead. So, all complains are gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can either **upgrade the Gradle version** likes Andreas's answer or **downgrade the java version** if needed.

Follow the link to change JAVA_HOME to downgrade JAVA. [How to set JAVA_HOME in Mac permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702702/how-to-set-java-home-in-mac-permanently)