# $JAVA_HOME not setting correctly

Tags: java, bash, macos, terminal, environment-variables

I have both java 14 and 8 installed on my laptop but want to use 8 by default so I'm trying to set my JAVA_HOME to use -v 1.8.

In ~/.bash_profile I added the line `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`. Immediately after doing this `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns the correct path and `java -version` returns the correct version. However, if I close terminal and open it again, `echo $JAVA_HOME` results in a blank line and `java -version` shows java 14. After editing .bash_profile I did do `source ~/.bash_profile` and when I reopen the terminal and do `nano ~/.bash_profile` the line setting JAVA_HOME is still there. Why can't I permanently set it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set JAVA\_HOME in Mac permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702702/how-to-set-java-home-in-mac-permanently)

Comment: Could be that `.bash_profile` is not being executed automatically. Mac's default shell isn't bash any more. You could try putting it in `.profile` instead.

Comment: Is your terminal set up to use a login shell? If not, it won't source bash_profile by default. Terminal settings => General => "Shells open with"

Comment: @khelwood I did try this but still the same result. It works at first but if I close terminal and reopen, echo $JAVA_HOME is blank again and java -version is 14 again.

Comment: @glennjackman Mine is set to open with default login shell

Answer (score 0):

Managed to answer my own question. My terminal is using zsh not bash so I just had to set it in .zshenv not .bash_profile