# Eclipse doesn't open because of popup to install jdk

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, installation

[image]

I am trying to install Eclipse (2018-12) on Mac but I get a popup as attached. I have installed Java 8 using sdkman located at home//.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.292.j9-adpt

I tried installing java 6 as well but that didn't help much.

Comment: I have never used [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/). On my Macs, I just download a build from one of the many JDK vendors such as AdoptOpenJDK/Adoptium or Azul Systems (or Amazon, BellSoft, Oracle, Microsoft, Red Hat/IBM, SAP, Pivotal, etc.). These vendors provide either an installer, or a folder. Both works. To install a. folder, merely drag to your boot drive > Library > Java > JavaVirtualMachines, and enter your system admin password at prompt. To verify, go to Terminal and type `java --version`. To uninstall, merely do a "Move to Trash" in the Finder, and supply your password.

Comment: Java is installed properly on my machine
java -version output is 
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"

But I still get the error (as per the screenshot) when trying to open eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing JAVA_HOME variable?
http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/
Or you have to add your JDK to PATH?
[How to set JAVA_HOME in Mac permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702702/how-to-set-java-home-in-mac-permanently)

Bear in mind that

> A Java 8 or newer JRE/JDK is required to run all Eclipse 2018-12
> packages based on Eclipse 4.10, including running the Installer. The
> reasoning behind requiring Java 8 are discussed here

so definitely your eclipse will not work with Java 6.

Comment: I see java_home is already set properly to :
echo $JAVA_HOME output is /Users/tiya/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
 and

Java is installed at /Users/tiya/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.292.j9-adpt

and sdkman's current is 1.8

But I still get the screenshot error while trying to install eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I have found under the link some information about required JDK 64 bit for macos version of Eclipse
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation

> The latest release of Eclipse requires a 64-bit JVM, and does not support a 32-bit JVM.

> If you are using Eclipse to do Java development, or are on macOS,
> install a JDK. In all cases, Eclipse requires a 64-bit JVM A Java
> Development Kit (JDK) includes many useful extras for Java developers
> including the source code for the standard Java libraries.

Please check if your java is 64bit JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my Mac to Big Sur, but still there was this problem. The problem was fixed by installing Eclipse Installer and then using that to install Eclipse.