# Maven Issues on OSX

Tags: java, maven

Maven is creating problems for me showing -
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

This error came up when I updated the .mavenrc with JAVA_HOME -
mavenrc content - export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_331.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

my 'which java' showing - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_331.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Before updating the mavenrc file. when I was trying to do mvn package - showing -
Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/../lib/tools.jar

I don't know what is the issue here. But m stuck and need help.

Comment: Can you please try setting JAVA_HOME as - export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_331.jdk/Contents/Home/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set JAVA\_HOME in Mac permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702702/how-to-set-java-home-in-mac-permanently)

Comment: You can also use SDKMAN (https://sdkman.io/) on macOS to make it easy to install JDK's and Maven.

Comment: Based on that `showing - Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0` I would check the used project because using a project which usses tools.jar is very old and outdated....