Flutter Doctor Error: Android Toolchain error- can not execute to determine the version
I'am facing below error while running flutter doctor on may Mac machine with M4c chip. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue. Below is the error after running flutter doctor -v command.
`[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/amit/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at:
      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    ✗ Cannot execute
      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java to
      determine the version`

I tried every solution out there on internet but not working. Please help me with a solution , this is first time i am using MacOs.
Thanks.

I forgot to ask, what IDE do you use?

Visual Studio Code

I've decided to undelete my answer because I was hoping that it could help you somehow.

For me, Android Studio is useful when I have to verify something, such as some development tool configurations. So, you can still use VS Code for general use in development. But when you want to verify something more easily, you can use Android Studio sometimes. Just give it a try!

Check if java -version returns the proper version in terminal. You may need to do some tinkering to point your machine to your java installation. Refer to this answer for help with Java. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19663996/19633851

Let's try to simplify the troubleshooting process first:
Please go to your Android Studio's File > Project Structure...
Then select your installed Java SDK by this way:

Note: You can also verify there if you properly selected the corresponding Java SDK.
After selecting, click apply, and then ok.
Please consider doing File > Invalidate Caches...
After doing these things. Execute flutter doctor -v again.
Make sure you set the proper PATH and JAVA_HOME in your ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES. Here's what I set for PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin and for JAVA HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21 it should be added in your system variables section.
UPDATE
For instant checking of your PATH and JAVA_HOME setup,
In Windows, open your command prompt, then execute these commands:
for checking your PATH
where java

for checking your JAVA_HOME
echo %JAVA_HOME%

I hope it helps!
